# Tikz curve not consistent with different computers

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

I am trying to draw a curve in pgf/tikz using \draw .. controls.

When I compile my .tex file at home, I get the graph on the left, which is the right one. However, when I compile my .tex on my office computer, I get the graph on the right.

[image]

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (8cm, 0) node(a4){} -- node[below=0.4cm]{$\mathrm{log} \left( \Delta K \right)$} +(7cm, 0) -- +(7cm, 5cm) -- +(0cm, 5cm) node[above left]{d)} -- node[rotate=90, yshift=0.4cm]{$\mathrm{log} \left( \frac{\mathrm{d} a}{\mathrm{d} N} \right)$} +(0, 0);
        \draw (a4) +(1cm, 0) .. controls +(0cm, 4cm) and +(-2.5cm, 0) .. +(5cm, 4.5cm);
        \draw[dotted] (a4) +(2.5cm, 0) node[below]{$\Delta K_{th}$} .. controls +(0.5cm, 2cm) and +(-1cm, -1cm) .. +(5cm, 3cm) .. controls +(1cm, 1cm) and +(0cm, -1cm) .. +(6cm, 4.5cm);   
        \draw[->, >=triangle 60, very thick] (a4) +(2.5cm, 2.2cm) -- node[above]{\begin{tabular}{ l } Conc. H $\downarrow$ \\ Fréq. $\uparrow$ \\ R $\downarrow$ \end{tabular}} +(4cm, 2.2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas how to correct this? Both computers are Windows-based and use MikTeX.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to TeX.SX. Please post a compileable code snippet (including the `usepackage` and `\documentclass` bits). Only then people will be able to reproduce and maybe solve your problem. Ideally also give some details about the software versions you're using.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your comment. I edited my post accordingly. Have a good day.

Comment: Are both installations kept up-to-date?

Comment: On ``OSX``  and ``TeXlive 2015`` and with packages updated, I get the (correct) picture on the lhs. Perhaps the older version has a bug.

Comment: It could be one uses the FPU and the other doesn't.

Comment: Put `\pgfversion`  in both computers after `\begin{document}` and check the numbers

Comment: I've checked also - older pfgversion 2.10 gives wrong picture.  Fresh version 3.0 gives correct picture. Both MikTeX and Win

Comment: ... of topic: default units for coordinates are cm, sou you not need to write. than instead `\mathrm{log}` you can simply write `\log`. And with recent TikZ I reproduce your correct image. It seems, that @Olga K discover source of your troubles

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but does the problem persist if `++` is used for the Bézier control points instead of `+`?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated my pgfversion to 3.0 and now it works fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by updating packages. (see comments)